# Postgres volatile create function joined with table that it inserted into

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, volatile

I have a pair of tables where the first table stores immutable "parent" objects, and the second table stores the mutable aspects of those objects, keeping a full history of all those values.  To make things a bit faster when setting the values for a given parent, especially when the parent may not yet exist, I'm trying to get a stored procedure that will find the parent, create it if it doesn't exist, and then create the mutable piece attached to that parent, and return the mutable piece.  Unfortunately, when I try to then join that back against the parent, the result is empty if the parent didn't already exist.

Example setup:

```
create table myvars (
  id serial unique,
  name text
);

create table myvalues (
  id serial unique,
  varid int references myvars(id),
  value text
);

insert into myvars (name) values('var1'), ('var2');

insert into myvalues (varid, value) values (1, 'val11'), (1, 'val12');
```

And the stored procdure for this:

```
create or replace function find_or_create_value(_var text, _value text)
returns setof myvalues
as $$
declare
  v myvars;
begin

  select * into v
  from myvars var where _var = var.name;

  if not found then
    insert into myvars (name) values(_var)
    returning * into v;
  end if;

  return query insert into myvalues (varid, value) values(v.id, _value) returning *;
end
$$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

Finally, the failing query:

```
select * 
from find_or_create_value('foo2', 'bar2') fcv 
join myvars mv 
  on fcv.varid = mv.id;
```

I have come up with a workaround for now, which is to do the join inside the stored procedure, and return a table of two records, and then the caller doesn't need to do the join. However, that seems a bit counter-intuitive to me, and also slightly less clean since I don't always need that extra information, so I'd rather the caller make the choice about whether to include the myvars data or not through joining when necessary, and not when not necessary. I'm hoping to find a way to get this to work returning only the one record of myvalues without the myvars record.

*Edit:*

I should also point out that the stored procedure "works" in that the insert is successful. And the query from it works. But when I join it against the table where it just created the secondary value, that doesn't work as in the ON condition is apparently unsatisfied even though the stored procedure guarantees that there will be a match.

Comment: Seem to be working fine here http://rextester.com/GIVO31083

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the insert works, but the select doesn't return anything, and I think your link shows that in that there's no output from the select from `find_or_create_value`.

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening. The function is working as expected . You can see it here http://rextester.com/PJGJ97762. The problem is with the join. Because everything is on the same transaction the `myvar` table is holding the original version before the function is executed and not the updated result by the function

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/PJGJ97762)**

change your function to:

```
create or replace function find_or_create_value(_var text, _value text)
returns setof myvalues
as $$
declare
  v myvars;
begin

  select * into v
  from myvars var where _var = var.name;

  if not found then
    insert into myvars (name) values(_var)
    returning * into v;
  end if;

  insert into myvalues (varid, value) values(v.id, _value);

  return query SELECT * FROM myvalues;
end
$$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

Comment: I must said, I don't know why your function doesn't work because seem very logical. But know what was probably wrong so I just try this way and seem to do the job.

Comment: a) you'll notice that you're returning ALL the values, not just the one that we found (or created), and b) your output is still missing the new `foo2` variable.